# How to inject a Stateless Session Bean into a Message Driven Bean?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, message-driven-bean, stateless-session-bean

I'm trying to inject a remote stateless session bean in a message driven bean.

I've been looking this post:
 [How to inject a Session Bean into a Message Driven Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465033/how-to-inject-a-session-bean-into-a-message-driven-bean)

The Session Bean and the Message Driven Bean are in two diff.

Here an exemple of what i've tried to inject my EJB :

```
@EJB(beanName="TraitementBeanRemote")
private TraitementBeanRemote traitementBeanRemote;
```

The application throws a NamingException :

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '#com.generator.traitement.TraitementBeanRemote' in SerialContext
```

My environement : Netbeans 7.4 / Glassfish 4.0

Does someone have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

If this Session Bean is deployed on the same server, then I recoment to add to it a local interface. EJB can have @Remote and @Local interfaces at the same time.